# Opengl Es update normals for each vertex in an animation

Tags: opengl, matrix, opengl-es, 3d

Below code ([original is here](https://github.com/danginsburg/opengles-book-samples/blob/master/LinuxX11/Chapter_8/Simple_VertexShader/Simple_VertexShader.c)) doesn't update normals, how can I update normals too?

Assume that there is a normals attribute in userData and related changes are made for vertex shader. And also first NULL in the line 76 was changed to `&userData->normals` etc.

```
///
// Update MVP matrix based on time
//
void Update ( ESContext *esContext, float deltaTime )
{
   UserData *userData = (UserData*) esContext->userData;
   ESMatrix perspective;
   ESMatrix modelview;
   float    aspect;

   // Compute a rotation angle based on time to rotate the cube
   userData->angle += ( deltaTime * 40.0f );
   if( userData->angle >= 360.0f )
      userData->angle -= 360.0f;

   // Compute the window aspect ratio
   aspect = (GLfloat) esContext->width / (GLfloat) esContext->height;

   // Generate a perspective matrix with a 60 degree FOV
   esMatrixLoadIdentity( &perspective );
   esPerspective( &perspective, 60.0f, aspect, 1.0f, 20.0f );

   // Generate a model view matrix to rotate/translate the cube
   esMatrixLoadIdentity( &modelview );

   // Translate away from the viewer
   esTranslate( &modelview, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0 );

   // Rotate the cube
   esRotate( &modelview, userData->angle, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

   // Compute the final MVP by multiplying the 
   // modevleiw and perspective matrices together
   esMatrixMultiply( &userData->mvpMatrix, &modelview, &perspective );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal transformation matrix is the inversed transpose of the modelview matrix. So you have to calculate that and provide in an additional uniform to transform the normals with.

Comment: Since the matrix only consists of rotations and translations, there's no need for these calculations. The top-left 3x3 sub-matrix of the full 4x4 matrix can be used to transform the normals. Or equally valid, apply only the rotation to the normals, without the translation.